# Need to select a formatted string in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So,

```
for s in soup.findAll("tag", {"id" : re.compile('i[0-9]*')}):
```

The id I'm trying to find is of the type ixxxxxx where 'x' are digits and these need to be selected from a set of ids of the form (Alphabet)XXXXXX. This still gives false positives and isn't limited to six digits. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: six digits `[0-9]{6}`

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html, you can put a limit on [0-9] and check out what * does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will match a string with 5 characters and 6 digits.

```
>>> bla = re.compile(u'^[A-Za-z]{5}\d{6}$')
>>> bla.match('abcde123456').group()
'abcde123456'
```

Comment: I realise that. What I'm looking for is a way to match one specific alphabet followed by 6 random digits, Eg- i123456 or i847564

Comment: This works in python cli: foo = re.compile(u'^i\d{6}$') or if you have a range of characters: foo = re.compile(u'^[ia]\d{6}$')